# Communication between Raspberry Pi , Arduino and Webserver using PHP

Tags: php, python, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi2, arduino-uno

I am working on a project at the moment that hosts a webpage on a Raspberry Pi which I would like to send few commands to the Arduino via USB which   makes  LED's glow .

The Communication between The Raspberry Pi and The Arduino is flawless .

The only real problem is I cant seem to reach my Arduino from the webpage .  my server doesn't seem to be connecting to my PI .

Below are the codes :-

Arduino:

```
const int ledPin1 = 13; 
const int ledPin2 = 8;
const int ledPin3 = 9;

void setup(){
pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop(){
if (Serial.available()) {
light(Serial.read() ­- '0');
}
delay(500);
}


void light(int n){
switch(n)
{
case 1:
digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH); 
delay(1000); 
digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);   
delay(1000);
break;
case 2:
digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH); 
delay(1000); 
digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
delay(1000);
break;
case 3:
digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH); 
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW); 
delay(1000);
break;
}
}
```

Python codes 
(client.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import socket
import sys 



TCP_IP = '169.254.181.84' 
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = str(sys.argv[1])
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
print "received data:", data
```

Python code 2:

(lec.py) for PI

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import serial
import time
import subprocess
dev =subprocess.check_output('ls /dev/ttyACM*',shell=True)
print dev
try:
ser = serial.Serial(dev.strip(),9600)
print "Arduino Connected"
except:
print "Arduino not connected"
def server():
global ser
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connection address:', addr
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: continue
    print "received data:", data
    if data == '1':
        conn.send("Blue light Glowing")
        conn.close()
        ser.write('1')
        time.sleep(1)
    elif data == '2':
        conn.send(" Red light blowing")
        conn.close()
        ser.write('2')
        time.sleep(1)
    elif data == '3':
        conn.send(" Green light blowing")
        conn.close()
        ser.write('3')
        time.sleep(1)
    elif data == '7':
        conn.send('bye bye')
        conn.close()
        ser.close()
        exit(0)
    else :
        ser.write(data)
        aa =  ser.readline()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print aa
        conn.send(aa)
        conn.close()


TCP_IP = '169.254.181.84'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(5)
print 'server started'
server()
```

Html code :

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Enter Command: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Welcome.php code:

```
<html>
<body>
Command is <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
<?php
$command=$_POST["name"];
$a = "python /home/client.py ";
$b= $a.$command; 
$last_line = system($b, $retval);
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line; . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried it but of no avail .

I would like to add that my script is responding to my queries as I can see a green light glow on Raspberry Pi board when pressing the submit button, but Arduino isn't getting those queries.

Why won't the Arduino receive the queries I am submitting through the webpage?

for more info please view this video on youtube

Visit http://https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2-nXbi3qmk/

Anyone please help me to debug the Problem and make life simpler and easier

Thanks

Be well !!

Comment: Hello Wassaf. Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for providing such a complete question. Alas, it will be difficult to come up with a confident answer, because most people here will not be able to replicate your environment in order to try to reproduce the problem you're having. I recommend you try to reduce your problem to the bare minimum required to demonstrate it. This exercise may also help you identify the problem yourself! Also, check permissions, and check your web server log for errors. I suspect that the user that runs your web server does not have access to `/dev/ttyACM*`.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti I will try with your method .